# execution reverted despite not writing to the blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, decentralized-exchange

I am attempting to read the value of a token on a DEX. When I run the code I get **execution reverted** despite not writing to the blockchain. Code is reproducible with your own Infura api key.

Any ideas why I get this error?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "github.com/jimlawless/whereami"
    "log"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    // Replace these values with your token address and DEX router address
    tokenAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x2B6d9f563d7CB1398C113ABb6DE615F9cDa3F0aA")     //Some random token
    dexRouterAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D") //Uniswap

    // Connect to a local Ethereum node using ethclient.Dial
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/USE_YOUR_OWN_API_KEY")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    // Call the getAmountIn function on the DEX router contract
    amountIn, err := callGetAmountIn(client, dexRouterAddress, tokenAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Print the result
    fmt.Println("Result of getAmountIn:", amountIn)
}

func callGetAmountIn(client *ethclient.Client, dexRouter, token common.Address) (*big.Int, error) {
    // Prepare input parameters for the getAmountIn function
    amountOut := big.NewInt(100) // Example output value

    // Pack the input parameters
    data := getFunctionSelector("getAmountIn(uint256,uint256,uint256)", amountOut, big.NewInt(0), big.NewInt(0))

    // Create a CallMsg to perform a static call (no state changes)
    msg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        To:   &dexRouter,
        Data: data,
    }

    // Call the contract function
    output, err := client.CallContract(context.Background(), msg, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New(err.Error() + "@" + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    // Unpack the output values
    result := new(big.Int)
    result.SetBytes(output)
    return result, nil
}

func getFunctionSelector(signature string, params ...*big.Int) []byte {
    // Calculate the function selector by taking the first 4 bytes of the hash of the signature
    functionSelector := common.BytesToHash([]byte(signature)).Bytes()[:4]

    // Combine the function selector and the packed parameters
    return append(functionSelector, common.LeftPadBytes(params[0].Bytes(), 32)...)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Keccak256 function in "golang.org/x/crypto/sha3"：

```
func getFunctionSelector(signature string, params ...*big.Int) []byte {
    // Calculate the function selector by taking the first 4 bytes of the hash of the signature
    hash := sha3.NewLegacyKeccak256()
    hash.Write([]byte(signature))
    functionSelector := hash.Sum(nil)[:4]

    // Combine the function selector and the packed parameters
    for _, param := range params {
        functionSelector = append(functionSelector, common.LeftPadBytes(param.Bytes(), 32)...)
    }
    return functionSelector
}
```

AND

Change Params:

```
 data := getFunctionSelector("getAmountIn(uint256,uint256,uint256)", amountOut, big.NewInt(1000), big.NewInt(1000))
```